# Filter record based on most recent record for Each ID in Google Data Studio

Tags: looker-studio

I have data with `ID` and `Date`. I want to fetch and aggregate data in given date range, but just the most recent record for any particular `ID`. Refer to following example:

```
+------+------------+-----+
|  ID  |    Date    | KPI |
+------+------------+-----+
| ID1  | 2019-06-19 | xx  |
| ID2  | 2019-06-20 | yy  |
| ID1  | 2019-06-28 | zz  |
+------+------------+-----+
```

When I specify the date range 01-June to 30-June, It should only display the records `2019-06-28` for `ID1` and `2019-06-20` for `ID2` but not `2019-06-19` for `ID1`.

Any suggestion on how to filter these records in Google Data Studio?

Answer (score 5):

One way that it can be achieved is by using a [Pivot Table](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7516660) and sorting the Date column by setting the **Number of Rows** to `1`:

### 1) Chart Type

- [Pivot Table](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7516660)

### 2) Fields

- ***Row Dimension #1***: `ID`
- ***Row Dimension #2***: `Date`
- ***Row Dimension #3***: `KPI`

### 3) Sort

- ***Row #1***: `ID`; ***Order***: Ascending; ***Number of Rows***: Auto
- ***Row #2***: `Date`; ***Order***: Descending; ***Number of Rows***: 1
- ***Row #3***: `KPI`; ***Order***: Ascending; ***Number of Rows***: Auto

[Google Data Studio Report](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/6a349f21-6e7d-4b8b-a52b-b2508ad63678) and a GIF to elaborate:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Not sure which data source you are using but if you are fetching data from BigQuery I find the easiest be to not use a table (with duplicated, timestamped rows) directly but rather a [Custom Query](https://support.google.com/looker-studio/answer/6370296?hl=en&ref_topic=10587734&sjid=3642405737578211330-EU#zippy=%2Cin-this-article). In the query you then just get the latest version of each row. Something like:

```
SELECT
      * except(rowNo)
    FROM (
      SELECT *,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY Date DESC) rowNo
      FROM `your.bq.table`
    )
    WHERE rowNo = 1
```