Get The Oldest Item In Each Queue From DelayedJobs on Looker
At work, we use Looker to visualize a lot of application events and data in our systems.
Currently, we want to build a dashboard to display data regarding our DelayedJobs processes.
For the most part, we have most visualizations, but we are struggling to make a visualization table that will show the oldest item in each queue:
Queue        | ID | Created Time
---------------------------
new_user     | 1  | 01/02/24 18:19:20
upload_data  | 4  | 01/02/24 21:22:23
email_list   | 10 | 01/02/24 01:02:03


I have tried to a multitude of SQL statements similar to and along the lines of:
SELECT DISTINCT ${queue}, ${id} FROM ${TABLE} GROUP BY ${queue} ORDER BY ${created_time} ASC

But it usually returns something like ERROR: more than one value was returned by subquery.
If I happen to have a passing SQL statement, it doesn't achieve what is intended, and usually appears like so:
Queue        | ID | Created Time
---------------------------
new_user     | 1  | 01/02/24 18:19:20
new_user     | 1  | 01/02/24 18:19:20
upload_data  | 4  | 01/02/24 21:22:23
upload_data  | 4  | 01/02/24 21:22:23

How can I improve or augment the query to where we can get a table to visualize the oldest item in each distinct queue?
At this point, given the way Looker performs SQL and displays data, I'm starting to think it is a futile effort. Any help would be appreciated.

see if this previous answer helps (nb reverse the order to get "oldest" instead of "newest") https://stackoverflow.com/a/64009936/2067753

Have you tried just using minimum? e.g. SELECT queue, id , min(created_time} as created_time FROM table GROUP BY queue, id ps: you don't need "distinct" when doing "group by".  see https://cloud.google.com/looker/docs/sql-runner-create-queries-and-explores#writing_a_sql_query_from_scratch

I figured it out.
I had to create a derived table in a second view with all the fields I wanted, create the respective dimensions in that view and then reference them in the original view so that I can format the data accordingly. It worked!
